# Select all integer columns except a few in python-polars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars

Consider I have a dataframe:

```
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs


df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'p': [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2],
        'x': list(range(6, 0, -1)),
        'y': list(range(2, 8)),
        'z': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, None],
        "q" : list('abcdef')
    }
)
```

df

```
shape: (6, 5)

p   x   y   z   q
i64 i64 i64 i64 str
1   6   2   3   "a"
2   5   3   4   "b"
1   4   4   5   "c"
3   3   5   6   "d"
1   2   6   7   "e"
2   1   7  null "f"
```

I need to select all the **integer columns** except `p` and `z`.

One way is to manually select each column but, it is not feasible if there are hundreds of columns.

What could a better and efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use polars' [column selectors](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html) to create a selector for all integers columns. Then, you can use [`pl.Expr.exclude`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.exclude.html) to exclude column *p* and *z* from the selection.

```py
import polars.selectors as cs

df.select(cs.integer().exclude("p", "z"))
```

Answer (score 2):

On searching:

I found one more way:

```
df.select(pl.col(pl.INTEGER_DTYPES).exclude('p','z'))
```